# Pricing on "deleted" objects in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When deleting an object in s3 , while versioning is enabled , it only adds a "delete marker" on the previous data so that it's hidden.

I wanted to know if I still get charged for the hidden data even though I "deleted" it ?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you still get charged for those 'deleted' objects. With versioning enabled, there really is no 'deleting', only hiding. Of course, you can Permanently Remove an object which removes its version.

Answer (score 7):

Yes for sure you get charged. Not just that if you have like 5 versions of an object; you have to pay for storage of all 5 objects.